# python 2.4 replica synchronize changes get system error (0)

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-9.2, replication

I have python scripts to synchronize changes between 2 geodatabases, the script working well before and after I remove 2 feature classes from one replica, and create a new replica using these 2 feature classes, all my replica cannot be synchronized using the following script:

```
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting, smtplib

# Create the Geoprocessor object
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

# Set the necessary product code
gp.SetProduct("ArcInfo")

gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files (x86)/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Data Management Tools.tbx")


# Local variables...
replica_sde__2_ = "C:\\Connections\\replica.sde"
user_prod_sde__2_ = "C:\\Connections\\user_prod.sde"

# Process: Synchronize Changes...


gp.SynchronizeChanges_management(replica_sde__2_, "DBO.Replica1", user_prod_sde__2_, "FROM_GEODATABASE2_TO_1", "IN_FAVOR_OF_GDB2", "", "")
```

I got system error (0) and I failed to find any detail for this error.

I am using python 2.4 and ArcGIS desktop 9.2.

Anybody has the experience on this?

Comment: was that the entire error message?  Can you paste the entire message as text into your question.  Usually python errors include info about line numbers and modules

Comment: Hi Midavalo, the whole message is:  system error (0): unexpected error. failed to execute (synchronizeChanges).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a formatting issue.

Try editing your code like this:

```
replica_sde__2_ = r'C:\Connections\replica.sde'
user_prod_sde__2_ = r'C:\Connections\user_prod.sde'
```

Or:

```
replica_sde__2_ = '''C:\\Connections\\replica.sde'''
user_prod_sde__2_ = '''C:\\Connections\\user_prod.sde'''
```

Comment: Thank you jbalk, I change the formatting but the result still the same.

Comment: Sorry I can't help more.  I use python 3.4 and 2.7 and ArcGIS 10.3 and I'm not familiar with the previous versions.  As far as I can tell, the script  should work.  Does it work if you use the synchronize changes tool in the toolbox outside of a script (do it manually)?